# How to relate voltage Output to temperature with a Wheastone bridge

Tags: microcontroller, measurement, temperature, thermistor

I have a circuit like the one below : [image: circuit]

with R1=10kOhms, R2 = R4 = 20kOhms and R3 is my thermistor (=10kOhms at 25°C).

I want to read the voltage V-Out on an arduino so that I can measure a temperature.

My question is, how can I link my changes in voltage to the temperature ?

Everything is a bit blurred in my head with the Steinhart–Hart....

Comment: Why not use a free sim tool?

Comment: What is it ? Where should I use it ?

Comment: You can download LTSpice for free. It's a steep learning curve but any EE of note will use a sim tool (either LTSpice or a paid-for version).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a trick if you make R4 to be 20k.

The log(ish) law of most thermistors affords a nice cheat. If you make R4 to be equal to the thermistor resistance at the middle of your temperature range, then the voltage out of the R3/R4 junction is very linear with temperature over +/-5 degrees C, and not far from linear over +/- 10 degrees.

If you want to exceed that range, then you'll need to bite the bullet and work through what the thermistor resistance means for the output voltage at any given temperature. When you buy a thermistor, you'll be told the parameters of the Steinhart-Hart curve. Alternatively, take measurements of resistance at several different temperatures and fit the curve.

Although it looks fearsome, the Steinhart-Hart curve is easy enough to whack into a spreadsheet to get resistances, and then another column will give you divider output voltages. Either fit a simple curve to the range you're interested in, or pick some specific points that are close enough together so that linear interpolation doesn't cause too much error, and put a table of those in your Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

You can work out the voltage using Ohm's law and a spreadsheet program. Use that to define a lookup table for your Arduino. It's only a 10-bit ADC so you can do that with 1024 entries.

Also, you can leave out the op-amp and three resistors- just use a voltage divider. Chances are you will not be needing amplification unless you're looking at a really narrow span.

The Wheatstone bridge as shown has variable gain depending on the temperature (high gain at high temperatures, lower gain at lower temperatures), which is easy to calculate but I don't think it's a positive thing in most situations.